# data is not getting passed to dynamodb from s3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Data is not getting passed to dynamodb from S3. Looks like i am missing something. Please help me if anyone has worked on this requirement.

I have already written a code which is not throwing any error. Although at the same time data is not getting passed to dynamodb. Looks like i am missing something. I have already configured dynamodb table with primary key as CN. In txt file, first line is header and rest lines contain data. But data is not getting loaded to dynamodb.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb','ap-southeast-1')

table=dynamodb.Table('TF')
txtFileReader={};

def txt_reader(event,context):
  bucket_path = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name'];
  key_path = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'];

#value is getting printed for the below 2-prints
  print(bucket_path)
  print(key_path)


  txt_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_path,Key=key_path)
  txtFileReader = txt_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split('\n')

#for below print, data is good
  print(txtFileReader)

#looks like the issue is after defining the batch_write
def batch_write(table_name,txtFileReader):    
  table=dynamodb.Table('TF')
  print(table)

with table.batch_writer() as batch:
   for row in txtFileReader:

     print(txtFileReader)
     batch.put_item(Item = {
            'CN':row.split('|')[0],
            'SN':row.split('|')[1],
            'WF':row.split('|')[2],
            'SEPM':row.split('|')[3],
            'Conf':row.split('|')[4],
            'Last-Check-In':row.split('|')[5]

            })
```

Here is the sample file I am using

```
CN|SN|WF|sepm|Conf|Last-Check-In 
PCOT|HQL||1|G01|9/3/2018 07:01 
PR2|CND||1|G02|8/29/2018 19:01 
M7|F9M||1|G03|9/3/2018 10:10 
MA|8CG4||1|G04|8/27/2018 15:00
```

Comment: below is the data in txt file:
CN|SN|WF|sepm|Conf|Last-Check-In
PCOT|HQL||1|G01|9/3/2018 07:01
PR2|CND||1|G02|8/29/2018 19:01
M7|F9M||1|G03|9/3/2018 10:10
MA|8CG4||1|G04|8/27/2018 15:00

###before PCOT, all 4-columns are header

Comment: You didn't actually say how you are running your code or what it is meant to be doing, but it seems to start at `table.batch_writer()`, then loop through rows in `txtFileReader`. However, `txtFileReader={}`, so there are no rows to loop through. Thus, it doesn't do anything. Also, your `txt_reader()` and `batch_write()` functions are never used.

Comment: there was no any need to define this function: def batch_write(table_name,txtFileReader): since it was not letting connect "txtFileReader" which was calculated in first function to second function. I commented second function and put all the below loops and code within the first function only and it worked. Also there was one issue of data which i was taking, for one column, value was null which dynamodb was not taking since i was no where handling that part in code. I put some random values there and data successfully loaded to dynamodb.